# Как можно различить созданные мною потоки от остальных?

Tags: c++, многопоточность, winapi

У процесса есть как минимум один его основной поток, + какие-то библиотеки могут создавать и свои потоки. И я сам создаю себе потоки.

Предположим мне надо остановить все **свои** потоки, приостановить их (Suspend) или наоборот продолжить их работу (Resume). То есть работать надо либо со всеми моими потоками, либо с группами моих потоков. Группы должны формироваться по статусу Suspended || Active.

Так вот какие есть стратегии управления потоками ? Как-то можно пометить свои ? Мне на ум приходит только оболочкой их всех вызывать и самому следить за ними, хранить их ID или дескрипторы, статус каждого.

+ желательно не вылазить за пределы WinAPI.

Comment: Ну а как вы хотите приостанавливать поток, не зная его id?

Comment: Моих потоков - 500+ (большинство в момент времени спит), не моих - 1-4. Можно пройтись по всем потокам, получить дескриптор каждого и закрыть. Не хотелось бы харнить 500+ дескрипторов / ID ради 1-4 не моих потоков.

Comment: Вообще-то никто не стесняется хранить 100500 дескрипторов, с чего Вам бояться? Можете придумать секретный протокол общения со своими потоками. Свои будут знать, чужие нет. Но если нужно адресно приостанавливать поток, как это сделать без какого-то адреса (дескриптора, id)? Как выделить конкретный поток из множетва таких же?

Comment: Зачем 500+ потоков?

Comment: Давайте начнём с того, что приостанавливать потоки — плохая идея. Поток может в этот момент держать блокировку какого-нибудь глобального ресурса. Например, heap lock.

Comment: [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686345%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) сообщеает: «_This function is primarily designed for use by debuggers. It is not intended to be used for thread synchronization. Calling SuspendThread [...] can lead to a deadlock [...]. To avoid this situation, a thread within an application that is not a debugger should signal the other thread to suspend itself. The target thread must be designed to watch for this signal and respond appropriately._»